# download iis connector starting java app in iis

Tags: java, tomcat, iis

I just installed a java app under iis in a 2008 r2 server using tomcat and iis connector. When I try to open the app and open the first jsp page I see that as Index.jsp I download the connector dll.
  What I'm missing? It's an old app, so I don't have instructions for 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

You should be part of your log or code made ​​up, so we analyze the reasons, but now you can try to reinstall tomcat or check your jdk version is in java se 1.6 or java se 1.7, and java ee 5, hopefully help you.

Comment: this is a third party application and I don't have the code. Tomcat start correctly and I can access it from :8080. I have enabled the connector (latest version) in the ISAPI Restrictions, but if iis send me the binary dll instead of try to run I suppose there is some configuration problem.
in the log files I see nothing strange, seems the app is not started

Comment: Try on your local machine can access, java applications generally require: jdk + java ee 5 + tomcat 7, the best way is: You can experiment on myeclipse, if you do not mind, can provide some first party applications, or the name of the link, I can help you test, tomcat locally.

Comment: A step forward: going in Handler Mapping and setting Execute in Feature permissions now tells me that the file is not found

Comment: You should have the highest authority, so as to carry out more operations [such as installing or upgrading applications].